# Are there any hidden caveats about the following class template inheritance example?

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

I have been reading about class templates, specialisation and inheritance, but none of the examples provided elsewhere gave me quite what I needed. So I put together this simple example to illustrate my specific requirements.

**Background**

Say I have `class A`, which contains instances of `class B`. However, there are two different types of `B`, which I have defined in an `enum class` (Type 1 and Type 2), so I need two separate versions of `class B` which have some members specific to that type of `B`. There are two possible solutions:

- Solution 1: Make B a base class containing the common members and create derived classes `class B_Type1` and `class B_Type2`. So the base class holds the common members and the derived classes have their own additional members.

Issue: In `A`, I need to specify what `B`s I need (`B_Type1` or `B_Type2`), so this means that I need one base and two derived classes for A as well.
This is all made worse by the fact that the hierarchy in my actual program consists of four classes, not two. So I have to make base and derived classes for all four classes!

- Solution 2: Templatise `B`. That way I have only one class `B`, so I templatise `A` as well, no need for base or derived classes, and Bob's your uncle.

Issue: Types 1 and 2 have shared members but also different members, so I have to specialise the template (`template<> B<Type1>` and `template<> B<Type2>`. But this means that I have to implement the common members in both specialisations.

**Requirements**

The user should be able to instantiate `A` with one of the two types of `B` by supplying **only** an `enum class` as a template argument. They should have access to the members of the specialised `class B` corresponding to that `enum` value. There should be only one class of type A visible to the user (rather than `A_Type1` and `A_Type2` and resp. `B_Type1` and `B_Type2`). From my perspective, I don't want to have to implement common members of `B` in separate template specialisations, so I need a way to put common members into a single class, but the additional members should still reside in separate classes.

**Tentative solution**

I have come up with the following solution. My rudimentary knowledge and understanding of templates and inheritance notwithstanding, I'm actually pretty happy with the result. It gives the users centralised classes `A` and `B` so they don't have to worry about the specialisations. To me as a maintainer the benefit is that I have a place to stick the common members of each class while still providing access to the additional members of the class of the corresponding type and not the other. It is fairly obvious that one concern is object size, which is why I need only those members which are relevant to the particular type. The solution goes against every example that I have seen so far - essentially, what should be the "base" class (such as `class B`) inherits from both "derived" classes (`B_Type1` and `B_Type2`). However, because of the specific template specialisation, only one of the two classes `B_Type1` and `B_Type2` is instantiated depending on the template argument provided.

Please let me know if any part of this is unclear, and I'll try to elaborate.

**Question**

Have I overlooked any monstrous hidden caveats related to this code waiting to jump and bite me when I least expect it? I don't want to spend a week refactoring my code just to find out that it brings out some awful dark side of C++.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class ClassBType
{
    Type1,
    Type2
};

template<ClassBType BT>
class B_Type1
{
};

template<ClassBType BT>
class B_Type2
{
};

template<ClassBType BT>
class A_Type1
{
};

template<ClassBType BT>
class A_Type2
{
};

template<>
class B_Type1<ClassBType::Type1>
{
    public:
    int type_1_specific_item_1 = 1;
    float type_2_specific_item_2 = 1.0;
    std::string dummy_1 = "Dummy var 1";
    std::string dummy_2 = "Dummy var 2";
    std::string dummy_3 = "Dummy var 3";
    std::string class_B_type_1 = "Type 1";

    inline int get_type_1_specific_item_1()
    {
        return type_1_specific_item_1;
    }

    inline float get_type_1_specific_item_2()
    {
        return type_2_specific_item_2;
    }

    inline std::string get_dummy_1()
    {
        return dummy_1;
    }

    inline std::string get_dummy_2()
    {
        return dummy_2;
    }

    inline std::string get_dummy_3()
    {
        return dummy_3;
    }
};

template<>
class B_Type2<ClassBType::Type2>
{
    public:
    int type_2_specific_item_1 = 2;
    float type_2_specific_item_2 = 2.0;
    std::string class_B_type_2 = "Type 2";

    int get_type_2_specific_item_1()
    {
        return type_2_specific_item_1;
    }

    float get_type_2_specific_item_2()
    {
        return type_2_specific_item_2;
    }
};

template<ClassBType BT>
class B : public B_Type1<BT>, public B_Type2<BT>
{
    public:
    // Common to both Type 1 and Type 2
    ClassBType d_type = BT;

    std::string get_type()
    {
        switch (d_type)
        {
        case ClassBType::Type1:
            return "Type 1";
            break;

        case ClassBType::Type2:
            return "Type 2";
            break;
        }
    }
};

template<>
class A_Type1<ClassBType::Type1>
{
    public:
    std::string class_A_type_1 = "Type 1";

};

template<>
class A_Type2<ClassBType::Type2>
{
    public:
    std::string class_A_type_2 = "Type 2";
};

template<ClassBType BT>
class A : public A_Type1<BT>, public A_Type2<BT>
{
    public:
    B<BT> b_inst;
};

int main()
{
    A<ClassBType::Type1> obj_a_type_1;
    std::cout << "Type of object B: " << obj_a_type_1.b_inst.get_type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Type of object A: " << obj_a_type_1.class_A_type_1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dummy var 1 from object B: " << obj_a_type_1.b_inst.get_dummy_1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dummy var 2 from object B: " << obj_a_type_1.b_inst.get_dummy_2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dummy var 3 from object B: " << obj_a_type_1.b_inst.get_dummy_3() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Specific item 1 from B: " << obj_a_type_1.b_inst.get_type_1_specific_item_1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Specific item 1 from B: " << obj_a_type_1.b_inst.get_type_1_specific_item_2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of object A: " << sizeof(obj_a_type_1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    A<ClassBType::Type2> obj_a_type_2;
    std::cout << "Type of object B: " << obj_a_type_2.b_inst.get_type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Type of object A: " << obj_a_type_2.class_A_type_2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Specific item 1 from B: " << obj_a_type_2.b_inst.get_type_2_specific_item_1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Specific item 1 from B: " << obj_a_type_2.b_inst.get_type_2_specific_item_2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of object A: " << sizeof(obj_a_type_2) << std::endl;

    // This produces a compilation error, which is good:
//    std::cout << obj_a_type_2.b_inst.get_dummy_1() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints the following:

```
Type of object B: Type 1
Type of object A: Type 1
Dummy var 1 from object B: Dummy var 1
Dummy var 2 from object B: Dummy var 2
Dummy var 3 from object B: Dummy var 3
Specific item 1 from B: 1
Specific item 1 from B: 1
Size of object A: 56

Type of object B: Type 2
Type of object A: Type 2
Specific item 1 from B: 2
Specific item 1 from B: 2
Size of object A: 32
```

Comment: "But this means that I have to implement the common members in both specialisations." - No, you can put them in a common base class `B_base`.

Comment: the base class version, together with a clone_pointer, could be worth trying

Comment: @TobiasBrandt Thank you, I'm glad I asked. So you are suggesting that `B_base` be templatised as`template<ClassBType BT> class B_base` and the specialisations be specialised as `template<> class B<ClassBType::Type1> : public B_base<ClassBType::Type1>` (resp. for Type2)?

Comment: @nodialtone The base class does not need to be a template. You could have `template <> class B<ClassBType::Type1> : B_base`.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt I think that the base class has to be a template because one of the common members (as well as some functions operating on it) is also templatised. I implemented your suggestion and it sort of works, but now I have encountered a separate problem with accessing the common elements through the derived class /sigh.../. The common members in `Class B_base` seem to be accessible only if the derived class is explicitly cast to the base class!

Comment: @TobiasBrandt By the way, your suggestion has brought me closer to what I need, so if you put it in an answer, I'll accept it.